# GET-параметр страницы

Tags: php, mysql, get

Возник такой вопрос, у меня страница профиля пользователя определяются GET параметром ( site.com/profile.php?id=1 ) в базе данных содержится таблица user в которую пользователи попадают после регистрации и им присваивается этот самый id. Как сделать, чтоб если запись в базе данных с таким id, то открывало страницу пользователя, а если записи с таким id нет, то открывало страницу 404. За ранее спасибо!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если отключить в браузере Javascript?
И это у нас фрагмент файла profile.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']) && (int)($_GET['id'])!==0 /*если придет строка в параметре*/   )
{
    //тут должно быть подключение к базе данных, если не предусмотрено заранее
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `таблица_users` WHERE id='".intval($_GET["id"])."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if(empty($result) )
    {
       header( 'Refresh: 0; url=/error404.html' );
    }

}
?>
<html>
Данные юзера, Личный кабинет
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']) and is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    //тут должно быть подключение к базе данных, если не предусмотрено заранее
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `таблица_users` WHERE id='".intval($_GET["id"])."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if($count[0] > 0)
    {
        die("<script>location.href='http://site.com/profile.php?id=".$_GET["id"]."'</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        die("<script>location.href='http://site.com/404'</script>");
    }
}
?>
```

Так или иначе, не забываем про безопасность и обязательно проверяем является ли `$_GET["id"]` числом или приводим к типу `intval($_GET["id"])` перед подстановкой в SQL запрос

Comment: хватит насиловать труп `mysql_*`

Comment: @vp_arth Уверен, у человека реализуется все именно на трупе

Comment: @vp_arth это дискриминация по некрофилии!

Comment: @Kyco4 Использовал ваш пример и вроде все получилось, если записи в БД нет, то открывается страница 404, **НО** когда запись есть, то страница не открывается, а идет множественная попытка ее открыть (в консоли Google Chrome выглядит так **13 Navigated to https://site.com/profile.php?id=1** ) и так продолжается бесконечно

Answer (score 0):

Данные из базы можно получить многими способами, поэтому этот момент пропустим.

Оба соседних ответа предлагают сделать ненужные редиректы. Если для страницы пользователя это ещё можно как-то оправдать, то страница 404 должна иметь статус 404, а не 302/200.

```
$user_id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : false;
$user = $user_id ? getUserDataById($user_id) : false;

if ($user) {
  // Рендерим страницу профиля пользователя include/echo/UserPage::render($user)
?>
<h1><?=htmlspecialchars($user['name'])?></h1>
...
<?php
} else {
  header('404 Not found');
  readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/errors/404.html');
  exit();
}
```

Comment: как-то ваш ответ для меня вообще темный лес, можете как-то объяснить куда подключать тут данные из БД и как сделать рендер страницы пользователя